# CSS for Opera Mini only

Tags: css, mobile, opera-mini, opera-mobile

I have some issues with css and Opera Mobile.

Without effecting other pages is there a way I can fix the css on opera mobile?

Here are my issues:

1. Links aren't underlined
2. CSS below does not center like button

   ```
   #likeButtonWrapper  //Center like button
       {
       margin: 1em auto;
       margin-top: 2em;
   }
   ```

Comment: Try to pass a fixed width value to your `#likeButtonWrapper`, it may help centering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `button` issue, `margin: 1em auto;` only works to center an item when it knows the `width` of the item.  Set a `width` and see if that fixes it.

My understanding is that Opera Mini disables link underlining automatically.  See http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=821082

Not sure if you can override it with a more specific style such as

```
a.link{text-decoration:underline;}
```

or

```
a{text-decoration:underline !important;}
```